# How to pass parameters with spaces as an array to RoboCopy in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am working on a script that needs RoboCopy switches to be passed in dynamically based on user input, hence using `array` seems like the best option. However I see the following issue when using I specify parameters like `/XF` that have a space and value.

**This works as expected:**

```
RoboCopy C:\Dir1 C:\Dir2 /NP /NFL /NS /NDL /NJH /NJS /XF *.config
```

**This works as expected:**

```
$Switches = @("/NP", "/NFL", "/NS", "/NDL", "/NJH", "/NJS", "/E")

RoboCopy C:\Dir1 C:\Dir2 $Switches
```

**This throws `ERROR : Invalid Parameter #10 : "/XF *.config"`:**

```
$Switches = @("/NP", "/NFL", "/NS", "/NDL", "/NJH", "/NJS", "/E", "/XF *.config")

RoboCopy C:\Dir1 C:\Dir2 $Switches
```

I tried few things like using quotes with `/XF` parameter but no success. Any hint/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try this, I can't test it but let me know..:

```
$Switches = @("/NP", "/NFL", "/NS", "/NDL", "/NJH", "/NJS", "/E", "/XF", "*.config")
```

Comment: @NitinBadole Good! Glad to help!

Answer (score 5):

My variant (more XD/XF parameters):

```
$RobocopyParams = @("/NP", "/NFL", "/NS", "/NDL", "/NJH", "/NJS", "/E")
$XD = @("Cookies", "His6", "SendTo", "Temp", "Temporary Internet Files", "Windows")
$XF = @("*.pif", "$UserName.INI", "$UserName.OPS", "$UserName.INI.*")
robocopy.exe @params /XD @XD /XF @XF
```

Comment: Thanks, When using PowerShell, your splat solution fixed my problems

Comment: Where is the `src` and `dest` defined?